# What is special about the string "NA" in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im beginner in Ruby/RoR and I came across to piece of code I couldn't find logical explanation to.

Here is a simple example I ran into the `rails console`

```
2.3.7 :032 >   1.51.round
 => 2 
2.3.7 :033 > "NA".round
 => "NA" 
2.3.7 :034 > "sponch-bob".round
RuntimeError: .round called for a String again... probably you expected a number here?
        from lib/string.rb:28:in `round'
        from (irb):34
2.3.7 :035 >
```

I think the example is explanatory enough.

the first line `1.51.round => 2` all seems fine

the second line `"NA".round => "NA"` wow, how come? `round` method is a string method as well?
If that is true then lets check another example: `"sponch-bob".round` and error is thrown.

What is going on here?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What does `"NA".method(:round)` return?

Comment: feels like there's been some monkey patching made in the project, extending String with instance method `round`. so there is no one better than you to tell us what is going on inside this method)

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not normal behaviour. There is no `round` method defined for strings in standard ruby.

*Judging by your error message*, someone has **extended the `String` class** with this additional method, in `lib/string.rb`.

For example, maybe it looks something like this:

```
class String 
  def round
    return self if self == "NA"

    raise ".round called for a String again... probably you expected a number here?"
  end
end
```

This implementation is not standard practice, and most would probably consider it a "hack"... But I'm *guessing* it's been added to better support coercion of "Not Applicable" fields, e.g. in a spreadsheet import file.